# javascript noob level syntax error

Tags: javascript

```
var age = Number(prompt("How old are you?"));

if(age >= 13) {
    console.log("You are old enough!");
    alert("You Are old enough!");
    console.log("You are at a Justin Bieber concert, and you hear this lyric 'Lace my shoes off, start racing.'");
    console.log("Suddenly, Bieber stops and says, 'Who wants to race me?'");

    var userAnswer = prompt("Do you want to race Bieber on stage?");
    if(userAnswer) "yes";
    {
        console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!");
    } else {
        console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'");
    }
} else {
    console.log("Sorry, You Are Not old Enough :( ");
    alert("Sorry, You Are Not old Enough :( ");
}
```

I'm getting:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'

If Anyone Could Help Me That Would Be Great :)

Comment: Change `if (userAnswer) "yes";` to `if (userAnswer == "yes") {`

Answer (score 3):

You need to change

```
if (userAnswer) "yes";
{
}
```

To

```
if (userAnswer == "yes")
{
}
```

Why?

the statement `if (userAnswer) "yes";` means check if userAnswer has a value (`if(userAnswer)`), and then an unexpected token of `"yes";`.

How does the correct answer work?

`if (userAnswer == "yes")` means check if userAnswer is equal to "yes" by using the `==` operator, which is a common comparative operator in many programming languages.

Tip: you may want to use `if (userAnswer.toUpperCase() == "YES")`, as it means `yes` can be entered in any case, e.g. `yEs` and `YEs`...

Answer (score 2):

This is for the prompt, you need to compare the userAnswer to your value:

```
if (userAnswer) "yes";
```

is invalid. change to

```
if (userAnswer == "yes")
```

However, this will only work if the user types in "yes" exactly, and not "OK", "yeah!" or similar.

To avoid this, you could use a confirm dialog, which will provide two options "OK" or "Cancel" instead.

```
if(confirm("Do you want to race Bieber on stage?")) {
```

Comment: Actually you do. prompt requires string input from a user, so if the user enters "no", prompt returns "no" which evaluates to "true".

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your second if statement.

```
if (userAnswer == "yes");
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `;` in if loop

```
age = prompt(" How old Are You ? ");
if( age >= 13) {
    console.log("You Are old Enough ! ");
    alert("You Are old Enough ! ");
    console.log("You are at a Justin Bieber concert, and you hear this lyric 'Lace my shoes off, start racing.'");
    console.log("Suddenly, Bieber stops and says, 'Who wants to race me?'");
    var userAnswer = prompt("Do you want to race Bieber on stage? ");
    if (userAnswer=="yes"){
        console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!");
   } else {
        console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'");
    }
} else {
    console.log("Sorry, You Are Not old Enough :( ");
    alert("Sorry, You Are Not old Enough :( ");
}
```

Comment: If is not a loop but a control (conditional) structure;)

Answer (score 0):

It would be more robust to change your `prompt` to `confirm` and check the boolean value which is returned then.

Using `prompt` will return a string which you explicitely have to check for a certain value (e.g. via a regex or an array of possible , valid answers). If a user typed `For sure` or `Hell, yeah!` or even a simple `YES` your check `userAnswer == "yes"` would fail.

so better use this:

```
var userAnswer = confirm("Do you want to race Bieber on stage? ");

if (userAnswer){
   /*...*/
```

Answer (score -1):

Since apparently nobody knows that prompt returns a string, here we go:

```
age = prompt(" How old Are You ? ");
if( age >= 13) {
    console.log("You Are old Enough ! ");
    alert("You Are old Enough ! ");
    console.log("You are at a Justin Bieber concert, and you hear this lyric 'Lace my shoes off, start racing.'");
    console.log("Suddenly, Bieber stops and says, 'Who wants to race me?'");
    var userAnswer = prompt("Do you want to race Bieber on stage? ");
    if (userAnswer == "yes") {
        console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!");
   } else {
        console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'");
    }
} else {
    console.log("Sorry, You Are Not old Enough :( ");
    alert("Sorry, You Are Not old Enough :( ");
}
```